# Was bedeutet "was von selber aus mir heraus wollte"?

Tags: word-usage, meaning-in-context, sentence-structure

Der ganze Satz lautet:

> Ich wollte ja nichts als das zu leben versuchen, was von selber aus mir heraus wollte. Warum war das so sehr schwer?

Quelle: *Demian*, Hermann Hesse.

Ich verstehe weder die Bedeutung noch die Satzstruktur dieses Satzteils.
Und wie funktioniert *heraus*?

Answer (score 3):

"Heraus" und "hinaus" beschreiben, dass etwas in irgendeiner Form von drinnen nach draußen gelangt. Beide können als eigenständige Adverbien verwendet werden

> Ich bin über das Alter für solche Abenteuer hinaus.

oder als Vorsilben für Verben

> Ich wollte aus dem Haus herausgehen, aber die Tür war abgeschlossen.

Sowohl die Unterscheidung zwischen "drinnen" und "draußen" als auch die Bewegung können wörtlich gemeint sein oder bildlich.

Der Unterschied zwischen "heraus" und "hinaus" liegt in der Perspektive. Wenn der Sprecher sich drinnen befindet, dann findet die Bewegung von innen nach außen *von ihm weg* statt, dann ist die Bewegung "hinaus":

> Ich bleibe im Haus, und mein Vater geht in den Garten hinaus.

Wenn sich der Sprecher umgekehrt draußen befindet, dann findet die Bewegung *auf ihn zu* statt, und man verwendet "heraus":

> Ich sitze auf dem Rasen, und mein Vater kommt aus dem Haus heraus.

Es gibt noch weitere solche Paare, etwa für den umkehrten Weg "hinein" und "herein". Wenn es von unten nach oben geht, gibt es "hinauf" und "herauf", umgekehrt "hinab" und "herab".

Jetzt zu Hesse. In dem Satz sagt der Sprecher, dass er auf eine bestimmte Art und Weise leben wollte, oder das zumindest versucht hat. Dabei verwendet er ein abstraktes "das", um die Art zu leben zu beschreiben. Er wollte also "etwas leben" oder "das leben, was...".

Der Relativsatz beschreibt die Art zu leben, die der Sprecher zu verwirklichen versucht hat. Und zwar wollte er das leben

> was von selber aus mir heraus wollte.

Es wollte also ein abstraktes Etwas heraus, es wollte ein abstraktes Etwas von innen nach außen. Nur mit dieser Information hätten wir

> ... das leben, was heraus wollte.

Dann ist da die Information, wo der (bildliche) Ausgangspunkt der Bewegung von innen nach außen ist:

> ... das leben, was *aus mir* heraus wollte.

Und schließlich noch die Information, wer oder was die Bewegung veranlasst hat:

> ... das leben, was *von selber* aus mir heraus wollte.

"Von selber" heißt hier so viel wie "von sich aus", "ohne äußeren Auslöser":

> Die Vase ist von selber heruntergefallen, ich habe sie nicht angestoßen!