# Wie verstehe ich "hinaus" von “die Arbeit wird in die Welt hinaus verlagert"

Tags: meaning, adverb

Der ganze Satz ist,

> Neu sind jedoch die Trends zum Crowdsourcing oder auch Crowdworking: Auch hier wird die Arbeit in die Welt hinaus verlagert, jedoch an Personen in ihren Dreißigern, überdurchschnittlich gebildet mit hohem kreativen Potential.

Warum wird *hinaus* benutzt? Kann ich es einfach weglassen?

Comment: Auf Englisch: hinaus verlagern = outsource (hinaus = out).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Die allgemeine Verwendung von "hinaus" und "heraus" habe ich bereits [bei Deiner anderen Frage erklärt](https://german.stackexchange.com/questions/67567/was-bedeutet-was-von-selber-aus-mir-heraus-wollte/67570#67570).

Wenn wir das Beispiel ohne "hinaus" betrachten

> Die Arbeit wird in die Welt verlagert.

dann wird einfach nur eine Ortsveränderung ausgedrückt. Es wird nichts darüber gesagt, in welcher Beziehung die beiden Orte stehen.

Wenn man aber sagt

> Die Arbeit wird in die Welt hinaus verlagert.

dann wird der Ort, wo die Arbeit bisher war, implizit als irgendeine Art von "Drinnen" definiert. "Die Welt" ist demnach implizit ein "Draußen" zu diesem "Drinnen". Was genau der Autor damit ausdrücken will, wäre vermutlich ein Thema für eine eigenständige Textanalyse.

Grammatikalisch korrekt ist also beides, die Version mit "hinaus" und die Version ohne. Der implizierte Subtext ist aber leicht unterschiedlich.